# Именование файлов в Javascript

Tags: javascript, code-style

Каковы правила по именованию файлов в Javascript? 
Почему некоторые файлы начинаются с большой буквы, а некоторые с маленькой?

Например:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Скорее всего в каждом файле с большой буквы декларация одноимённого "класса", а с маленькой - клиентский код либо обобщённый импорт всех классов выше. Если это так - вполне себе симпатичное соглашение.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как таковых правил и рекомендаций по именованию файлов не встречал. Но есть некоторые рекомендации, которых я стараюсь придерживаться во время именования файлов в JavaScript:

- Более привычно использовать имена файлов в нижнем регистре (лично для меня и всех проектов, в которых я веду работу).
- Не использовать пробелы в именах файлов, лучше использовать тире или точку. Использовать тире, когда слова связаны по смыслу, к примеру имя продукта в два слова через тире.Точку, когда идет разделение логики, к примеру имя модуля и версия - разделим точкой.
- Использовать номера версии в именах файлов, если таковые имеются.
- Использовать в именах файлов пространство имен, имя модуля, тип файла (на примере именования в jQuery). Например: `product-name.plugin-version.filetype.js` или `jquery.plugin-0.1.js`

> Код должен быть максимально читаемым и понятным. Для этого нужен
>   хороший стиль написания кода.

Хорошие ссылки для ознакомления:

- [Советы по стилю кода JavaScript](https://learn.javascript.ru/coding-style)
- [Правильный выбор имени переменной](https://learn.javascript.ru/variable-names)
- [What is the javascript filename naming convention?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7273431/5275890)
- [JavaScript Style Guide and Coding Conventions](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_conventions.asp)
- [Code Conventions for the JavaScript Programming Language](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html)

Answer (score 2):

Абсолютно неважно как именовать файлы(не рекомендуется с пробелами), считаю что хорошим тоном является именование файлов по стилю camelCase. Пример : `helloWorld.js, goodDay.js`